# Multiple option form not displaying

Tags: html, reactjs

so I'm trying to implement a multiple page form (like typeform) using react Js
When my input is a text field everything works fine
example

```
 <input id="input-2" type="text" placeholder="H/F" required />
  <label for="input-2">
    <span class="label-text">Sexe</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
```

But when the input is radio button it no longer displays

```
<div id="input-3" >
  <input type="radio" value="male" name= "sexe" required /> Male
  <input type="radio" value="female" name= "sexe" required /> Female
  <label for="input-3">
  <span class="label-text">Sexe?</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
  </div>
```

Sorry if the question seems obvious but I'm just starting with react js
Thank you

Comment: it show only html not js. Add few more details with what you have actually tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [isFormDisplay, setFormDisplay] = useState(false);

// DO LOGIC WHEN YOU WANT TO DISPLAY THE FORM OR NOT

return { 
    <>
    {!isFormDisplay &&  
      <input id="input-2" type="text" placeholder="H/F" required />
      <label for="input-2">
        <span class="label-text">Sexe</span>
        <span class="nav-dot"></span>
      </label> 
    }
    {isFormDisplay &&  
       <div id="input-3">
        <input type="radio" value="male" name= "sexe" required /> Male
        <input type="radio" value="female" name= "sexe" required /> Female
        <label for="input-3">
          <span class="label-text">Sexe?</span>
          <span class="nav-dot"></span>
         </label>
       </div>
    }
   <>
};
```

Comment: Why not a ternary?

Comment: I don't enough details about what he want to achieve, so I guessed it would solve the issue for him.

Comment: sorry but it did not work since my component is a class and not a function

Comment: You can pass the property of `isFormDisplay` to the component from the parent component